# Reinf + Java, erro MS0017 Assinatura do evento inválida. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: java, xml, certificado-digital, web-service

olá

Preciso de uma ajuda, pois estou preso no problema e não consigo vislumbrar a solução.

Ao enviar um lote para o Reinf, obtenho o retorno:

```
retornoEventos.1.evento.evtTotal.ideRecRetorno.status.regOcorrs.1.codResp        .: 
MS0017
retornoEventos.1.evento.evtTotal.ideRecRetorno.status.regOcorrs.1.dscResp        .:
Assinatura do evento inválida. Erro ao verificar a assinatura (tag 'Signature') com o certificado (tag 'X509Certificate'). Verifique se houve alteracao no arquivo apos o mesmo ter sido assinado.
```

O xml do lote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_05_01">
   <loteEventos>
      <evento id="ID2269897150062242019040311255000001">
         <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTomadorServicos/v1_05_01">
            <evtServTom id="ID2269897150062242019040311255000001">
               <ideEvento>
                  <indRetif>1</indRetif>
                  <perApur>2022-07</perApur>
                  <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                  <procEmi>2</procEmi>
                  <verProc>0.0.1</verProc>
               </ideEvento>
               <ideContri>
                  <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                  <nrInsc>26989715006224</nrInsc>
               </ideContri>
               <infoServTom>
                  <ideEstabObra>
                     <tpInscEstab>1</tpInscEstab>
                     <nrInscEstab>26989715006224</nrInscEstab>
                     <indObra>0</indObra>
                     <idePrestServ>
                        <cnpjPrestador>01294164000131</cnpjPrestador>
                        <vlrTotalBruto>1250,00</vlrTotalBruto>
                        <vlrTotalBaseRet>1250,00</vlrTotalBaseRet>
                        <vlrTotalRetPrinc>137,50</vlrTotalRetPrinc>
                        <indCPRB>0</indCPRB>
                        <nfs>
                           <serie>0</serie>
                           <numDocto>54321</numDocto>
                           <dtEmissaoNF>2022-07-18</dtEmissaoNF>
                           <vlrBruto>1250,00</vlrBruto>
                           <infoTpServ>
                              <tpServico>100000001</tpServico>
                              <vlrBaseRet>1250,00</vlrBaseRet>
                              <vlrRetencao>137,50</vlrRetencao>
                           </infoTpServ>
                        </nfs>
                     </idePrestServ>
                  </ideEstabObra>
               </infoServTom>
            </evtServTom>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
               <SignedInfo>
                  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                  <Reference URI="#ID2269897150062242019040311255000001">
                     <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                     </Transforms>
                     <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                     <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                  </Reference>
               </SignedInfo>
               <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
               <KeyInfo>
                  <X509Data>
                     <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                  </X509Data>
               </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
         </Reinf>
      </evento>
   </loteEventos>
</Reinf>
```

O node é assinado com o seguinte método:

```
    public void assinarInstanciaElemento(Element elementEvento, Certificado certificado) {

        try {
            String id = "";
            try {
                elementEvento.setIdAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_REINF, true);
                id = elementEvento.getAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_REINF);
            } catch (DOMException e) {
                elementEvento.setIdAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_ESOCIAL, true);
                id = elementEvento.getAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_ESOCIAL);
            }
            String referenceURI = "#" + id;
            //String referenceURI = id;
            //String referenceURI = "";
            
            XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
            
            ArrayList<Transform> transformList = new ArrayList<Transform>();
            TransformParameterSpec tps = null;
            Transform envelopedTransform = fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, tps);
            Transform c14NTransform = fac.newTransform("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315", tps);
            transformList.add(envelopedTransform);
            transformList.add(c14NTransform);
    
            String alias = certificado.getKeyStore().aliases().nextElement();
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) certificado.getKeyStore().getEntry(alias,
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(certificado.getSenha().toCharArray()));
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
    
            List<Serializable> x509Content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
            x509Content.add(cert);
            KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
            X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
            KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));
            
            Reference ref = fac.newReference(referenceURI, fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
                    transformList, null, null);
            SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(
                    fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                    fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null),
                    Collections.singletonList(ref));            
    
            XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
            DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), elementEvento.getParentNode());
            signature.sign(dsc);
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

E transformado para texto com o seguinte método:

```
    public static String nodeParaXml(Node node, boolean omitirDeclaracaoXml) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Transformer trans =  TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            
            if (omitirDeclaracaoXml || !(node instanceof Document)) {
                trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            } else {
                trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            }
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no"); 
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(os));
            
            return os.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Estou usando JDK 17.0.2 com o parametro -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode ser, ou alguma orientação ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de Java, mas, me parece que a função ´nodeParaXml()´ faz modificações no XML, como o encoding e a indentação. Uma vez que o XML é assinado ele não pode mais sofrer nenhuma alteração mesmo, senão a assinatura não vai bater com o hash do conteúdo.

Answer (score -3):

Superei essa crítica de assinatura alterando o código do assinador. Anteriormente, estava usando java nativo para assinar. Agora, o assinador está usando as classes da Apache do pacote "org.apache.xml.security".

O código do assinador ficou assim:

```
public static String assinar(Certificado certificado, String xml, String referenteURI) {
    
    final String signatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
    final String[] transformList = { 
            "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature",
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" };
    final String digestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
    
    String xmlAssinado = null;
    
    try {
        Init.init();
        ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, "");
        
        final Document doc = getDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        Element element = ((Element) doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild());
        if (element.hasAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_REINF)) {
            element.setIdAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_REINF, true);
        }else if (element.hasAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_ESOCIAL)) {
            //element.setIdAttribute(ATRIBUTO_ID_ESOCIAL, true);
            referenteURI = "";
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("elemento com o referenceURI id não encontrado.");
        }
        
        org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature sig = new org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature(doc, null, signatureMethod);
        doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(sig.getElement());
        
        final Transforms transforms = criarTransformacoes(transformList, doc);
        sig.addDocument(referenteURI, transforms, digestMethod);
        
        sig.addKeyInfo(certificado.getX509Certificate());
        sig.sign(certificado.getPrivateKey());
        
        xmlAssinado = getDocString(doc);
        
    } catch (XMLSecurityException | SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return xmlAssinado;
}

private static String getDocString(Document doc)
        throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no"); 
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");     
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));

    return os.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
}

private static DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilder() throws ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
    return factory.newDocumentBuilder();
}

private static Transforms criarTransformacoes(String[] transformList, final Document doc) throws TransformationException {
    final Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
    for (String transformUri : transformList) {
        transforms.addTransform(transformUri);
    }
    return transforms;
}
```

No maven, precisou das seguinte dependências:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

A solução foi baseada no assinador do TST: https://github.com/tst-labs/esocial/blob/master/src/esocial-jt-service/src/main/java/br/jus/tst/esocialjt/xml/assinatura/AssinaturaXmlServico.java